# Orthogonal group derived using tensor notation $f(v)=v_av_bm^{ab}$, instead of inner product notation $f(v)=v^Tv$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, inner-products, tensors, orthogonal-matrices

I wish to replicate the following proof using tensor notation. Let $v$ be a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. First I define this function:

$$
f(v)=v^Tv\\
$$

I now ask, what are the transformations that leave $f$ invariant:

$$
f(Ov)=(Ov)^T (Ov)=v^TO^TOv
$$

which is invariant iff $O^TO=I$.

---

Now using tensor notation, I write $f$ as follows:

$$
f(v)=v_av_bm^{ab}
$$

for a 2D vector:

$$
f(v)=v_0v_0m^{00}+v_0v_1m^{01}+v_0v_1m^{10} +v_1v_1m^{11}
$$

Then, if we assume the $m_{ab}$ is the identity matrix, we get:

$$
f(v)=v_0^2+v_1^2
$$

What happen when I inject a transformation into $f$? Is the following the correct approach?

$$
f(Ov) = (Ov)_a(Ov)_b m^{ab}
$$

How do I then eliminate $O$ such that the condition $O^TO=I$ emerges, using this kind of notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $O$ for which $v\mapsto Ov$ preserves $v^Tmv$ (where without loss of generality $m$ is symmetric, so is diagonalisable with real eigenvalues) are not in general the orthogonal $O$, but the solutions to $O^TmO=m$. Indeed$$(Ov)_a(Ov)_bm^{ab}=O_a^{\:c}v_cO_b^{\:d}v_dm^{ab}\equiv v_cv_dm^{cd}\iff m^{cd}=O_a^{\:c}O_b^{\:d}m^{ab}=(O^TmO)^{cd}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question: After the equivalence symbol, you have $m$ as a stand-alone symbol. Is the use of $m$ as a matrix, correct?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Yes; we're verifying $m=O^TmO$ by showing these matrices have the same ${}^{cd}$ entries.

Comment: I have having trouble understanding the term $mv_cv_dm^{cd}$. In this case, you have a matrix $m$ multiplied by a sum of scalars $v_cv_dm^{cd}$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Oh! Sorry, that particular $m$ [was a typo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m6Blqs0IgY). Thanks; fixed.

Comment: If I were to do it with a 4-tensor: $(Ov)_a(Ov)_b(Ov)_c(Ov)_dm^{abcd}$, I would end up with $m^{efgh}=O_a^eO_b^fO_c^gO_d^hm^{abcd}$. Can I then connect this a group such as $O^T$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay This question would be easier if you'd used a $3$-tensor, but OK. If $O$ satisfies that, as does $P$,$$\begin{align}(OP)_a^e(OP)_b^f(OP)_c^g(OP)_d^hm^{abcd}&=P_i^eP_j^fP_k^gP_l^hO_a^iO_b^jO_c^kO_d^lm^{abcd}\\&=P_i^eP_j^fP_k^gP_l^hm^{ijkl}\\&=m^{efgh}.\end{align}$$That proves closure. The other monoid axioms are trivial. Groups have one more axiom, invertibility, which depends on $m$'s properties. (I've assumed heretofore the original problem's matrix $m^{ab}$ is invertible, so $\det O=\pm1$.)

Comment: How would I formulate the constraint on $O$, such as $O^TmO=m$ but for the 4-tensor?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay When the number of indices is so large, you pretty much have to write it in index notation. You may find notation to circumvent this, but it will be less familiar, so would need an explanation to the reader anyway.

Comment: Thank you for all of this information.

Comment: New question; Can I set special requirements on the vectors products, such as $(v_a)^Hv_bm^{ab}$, where $(v_a)^H$ is the Hermitian conjugate of the vector - or to these transformations need to be 'embedded' in to $m^{ab}$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay I don't understand your question, but the same transformations more generally preserve $u_av_bm^{ab}$.

Comment: Suppose I would like $v_av_bm^{ab}$ to be invariant to the unitary group. For that I would need the elements $v_a$ to be the complex conjugate of the elements $v_b$. To achieve that, can I just define the function as $(v_a)^*v_bm^{ab}$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Yes, that amounts to replacing a transpose with an adjoint, which also conjugates. Then$$v^\prime=Uv\implies v^{\prime\dagger}=v^\dagger U^\dagger.$$